# Debugging with GDB on Unix: suspend execution

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb

I try to figure out how can I suspend a C-program execution with GDB **anywhere**.

If I have a loop with no breakpoints how can I just suspend it whenever I want?

I'm  also new to Unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctrl z should work just fine if you are using a unix terminal.